# Measure Tool - How to Copy Measurement Value to my Clipboard (Blender 2.80)?

Tags: measurement

How do I copy the active ruler/protractor's measurements to my clipboard in Blender 2.80?
In Blender 2.79, pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> could copy the value to the clipboard, but it doesn't work this way in Blender 2.80.
Always manually writing down or memorizing 5-digit measurements and calculating angles to decimal places is very time-consuming.